# How to fetch Value from a HTML Table in laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have a Dynamic Sortable Table where I can add or delete rows like[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAiyk.png)
There is a loop in my controller. This loop run 4 times on the basis of column number of the table. But my table has fixed column number and row number is variable. I want to run this loop on the basis of row number.
Here is my view page

```html
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'WorkBreakdownController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
<table class="table table-hover table-sortable" id="tab_logic" name="DataTable">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="text-center">
                                        <td style="width: 40%;">Process Name</td>
                                        <td style="width: 30%;">Machine Name</td>
                                        <td style="width: 10%;">Machine Qty</td>
                                        <td style="width: 10%;">SMV</td>
                                        <td style="width: 10%;">Action</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr id='addr0' data-id="0" class="hidden">
                                        <td data-name="ProcessName">
                                            {{Form::text('items[][ProcessName]', '', ['id'=>'ProcessName', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>''])}}
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-name="MachineName">
                                            <div class="form-group row-fluid m-auto">
                                                <select name="items[][MachineName]" class="form-control" id="MachineName" data-live-search="true">
                                                    <option value=""></option>
                                                    @foreach($machineName as $machineName)
                                                        <option value="{{$machineName->id}}">{{$machineName->MachineName}}</option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-name="MachineQty">
                                        {{Form::number('items[][MachineQty]', '', ['id'=>'MachineQty', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>''])}}
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-name="SMV">
                                        {{Form::number('items[][SMV]', '', ['id'=>'SMV', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>''])}}
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-name="del">
                                            <a name="del0" id="del0" class="btn btn-outline-danger row-remove"  value="del0">Delete</a>                        
                                            {{-- <button name="del0" class='btn btn-outline-danger row-remove'>Delete</button> --}}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
                                            <a id="add_row" class="btn float-right btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-secondary">Add Row</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
                                            {{Form::submit('Save', ['class'=>'btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary btn-block', 'name'=>'ProductInsert'])}}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>
```

and there is the controller

```html
$j=0;
            // $ProcessName_ID = $request->input('MachineName');
            foreach($request->input('items', []) as $item){
            $work_breakdown = new work_breakdown($item);
            $work_breakdown->SN = $j;
            $work_breakdown->ProcessName = $request->input("ProcessName{$j}");
            $work_breakdown->MachineID = $request->input("MachineName{$j}");
            $work_breakdown->MachineQty = $request["MachineQty{$j}"];
            $work_breakdown->SMV = $request["SMV{$j}"];
            $work_breakdown->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            $work_breakdown->save(); 
            $j++;
            }
```

It only iterates 4 times, not more than taht.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem in a tricky way. If anyone knows the standard way then please let me know. Here I changed my view page like this

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-sortable" id="tab_logic" name="DataTable">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="text-center">
                                        <td style="width: 2%;" class="text-white">SN</td>
                                        <td style="width: 38%;">Process Name</td>
                                        <td style="width: 30%;">Machine Name</td>
                                        <td style="width: 10%;">Machine Qty</td>
                                        <td style="width: 10%;">SMV</td>
                                        <td style="width: 10%;">Action</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr id='addr0' data-id="0" class="d-none">
                                        <td data-name="SN" class="d-none">
                                            <div class="form-group row-fluid m-auto">
                                            <input name="items[][SN]" type="text" class="form-control d-none" id="forIncrementalRow">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-name="ProcessName">
                                            {{Form::text('ProcessName0', '', ['id'=>'ProcessName', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>''])}}
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-name="MachineName">
                                                <select name="MachineName0" class="form-control row-fluid m-auto" id="MachineName" data-live-search="true">
                                                    <option value=""></option>
                                                    @foreach($machineName as $machineName)
                                                        <option value="{{$machineName->id}}">{{$machineName->MachineName}}</option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-name="MachineQty">
                                        {{Form::number('MachineQty0', '', ['id'=>'MachineQty', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>''])}}
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-name="SMV">
                                        {{Form::number('SMV0', '', ['id'=>'SMV', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>''])}}
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-name="del">
                                            <a name="del0" id="del0" class="btn btn-outline-danger row-remove"  value="del0">Delete</a>                        
                                            {{-- <button name="del0" class='btn btn-outline-danger row-remove'>Delete</button> --}}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="6" style="text-align: left;">
                                            <a id="add_row" class="btn float-right btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-secondary">Add Row</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="6" style="text-align: left;">
                                            {{Form::submit('Save', ['class'=>'btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary btn-block', 'name'=>'ProductInsert'])}}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>
```

and there is the controller

```html
$maxValue = product_details::max('id');
            $i=0;
            $j=0;
            foreach($request->input('items', []) as $item){
            
            $j++;
            // Create Post
            $work_breakdown = new work_breakdown($item);
            $work_breakdown->ProductID = $maxValue;
            $work_breakdown->SN = $j;
            $work_breakdown->ProcessName = $request->input("ProcessName{$j}");
            $work_breakdown->MachineID = $request->input("MachineName{$j}");
            $work_breakdown->MachineQty = $request["MachineQty{$j}"];
            $work_breakdown->SMV = $request["SMV{$j}"];
            $work_breakdown->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            $work_breakdown->save(); 
            }

            $userID = auth()->user()->id;
            

            //to delete unexpected row
            $maxValue2 = work_breakdown::where('user_id', $userID)->max('id');
            DB::delete('delete from work_breakdown where id = ?',[$maxValue2]);
```

This loop always save an extra row with null value, so I delete it after the loop

Answer (score 0):

Asuming that you only store text data not images and your ajax post call is correct you simply have to do following store function in your controller:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
  // I just call it device model here don't know your model name
  $device = Device::create($request->all());

  if($device) {
    return redirect()->route('device.index')->with('message', 'Success'); // return to device/index.blade.php with success message
  }

  return redirect()->route('device.index')->with('message', 'error'); // return to device/index.blade.php with error message

}
```

Comment: I have done this by changing my controller. Please check it. But I can only store from four rows of that table. If this table contains more than four rows then those values are not stored.

Comment: @MuslehuddinJuned I don't understand so it saves 4 rows like this `id - name - number - date` but not like this `id - name - number - date - more`?

Comment: it saves like this id1 - name1 - number1 - date1   id2 - name2 - number2 - date2     id3 - name3 - number3 - date3    id4 - name4 - number4 - date4       that's all. It can't save    id5 - name5 - number5 - date5 or anymore. That is only four rows saved but fifth or any more rows are not saved.

Comment: What happens if you `dd($request->all())`, you should see all the data, if not there is something wrong with your post call

Comment: Basically it's a loop. It's iterated only four times. But I don't understand why. At 1st to 4th times it works good. But at fifth times it doesn't fetch any data.

Comment: Again can you `dd($request->all())` in your controller method to check if you actually receive all the data from your table, just do that please and let me know what happened

Comment: Here I insert values at two data table. One inside loop and another outside. When use dd($request->all()) it shows me a different page. please visit this link for details:   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SWiWUPCgOnnCJnqiU4NDNT6Zp2poJwEZ